# Insert into table contains Repeated Record in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with very complex scheme (up to 2300 column)

in these columns I have RECORD type fields, someof them are in REPEATED mode,

The insert statement is generated by processor in the code,
but when test this insertion statement on BigQuery Web-UI I see an error,
after investigating the issue, I found that inserting array is not done in the appropriate way.

```
INSERT INTO Table_X (RECORD_FIELD) VALUES (
...

STRUCT([STRUCT(X), STRUCT(Y)]) as property_z
...
```

it this format is correct for inserting REPEATED fields?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (columns) VALUES (STRUCT([ STRUCT(...), STRUCT(...) ]), ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

Repeated fields are arrays, so you want to insert them as arrays:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (repeated_column)
    VALUES (ARRAY[ STRUCT(...), STRUCT(...) ]);
```

Note that the array is a single column,  You can include values for other columns in the `INSERT` as well.